# amCharts Candlestick/Boxplot Using a Custom X Axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boxplot, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm using amCharts to create a box plot for n number of different assets. Ideally, what I want is the x-axis to display the name/id of each asset and the Y axis display the values/scale for the boxplot. I've seen the examples given in the documentation: [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/candlestick-series/) and [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/tutorials/clustered-box-plot/), but this does not achieve the required result. The chart appears but all the data-points appear to stacked (see towards the left) against one corner.

[image]

Here's the code below:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import * as am5 from "@amcharts/amcharts5";
import * as am5xy from "@amcharts/amcharts5/xy";
import am5themes_Animated from "@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated";
import * as am5plugins_exporting from "@amcharts/amcharts5/plugins/exporting";

function App(props) {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    var root = am5.Root.new(props.name);

    // Set themes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
    root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

    //---------------------------------------------------CHART LOGIC------------------------------------//
    // Create chart
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
    var chart = root.container.children.push(
      am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
        focusable: true,
        panX: true,
        panY: true,
        wheelX: "panX",
        // wheelY: "zoomX",
      })
    );

    // Create axes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
    // var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
    //   am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
    //     baseInterval: { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
    //     renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
    //     tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
    //   })
    // );

    var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
      am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        categoryField: "date",
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
      })
    );

    var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
      })
    );

    var color = root.interfaceColors.get("background");

    // Add series
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
    var series = chart.series.push(
      am5xy.CandlestickSeries.new(root, {
        fill: color,
        stroke: color,
        name: "MDXI",
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        valueYField: "close",
        openValueYField: "open",
        lowValueYField: "low",
        highValueYField: "high",
        categoryXField: "date",
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
          pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
          labelText:
            "open: {openValueY}\nlow: {lowValueY}\nhigh: {highValueY}\nclose: {valueY},\nmediana: {mediana}",
        }),
      })
    );

    // mediana series
    var medianaSeries = chart.series.push(
      am5xy.StepLineSeries.new(root, {
        stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        valueYField: "mediana",
        categoryXField: "date",
        noRisers: true,
      })
    );

    // Add cursor
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
    var cursor = chart.set(
      "cursor",
      am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
        xAxis: xAxis,
      })
    );
    cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);

    var data = [
      {
        date: "2019-08-01",
        open: 132.3,
        high: 136.96,
        low: 131.15,
        close: 136.49,
      },
      {
        date: "2019-08-02",
        open: 135.26,
        high: 135.95,
        low: 131.5,
        close: 131.85,
      },
      {
        date: "2019-08-03",
        open: 129.9,
        high: 133.27,
        low: 128.3,
        close: 132.25,
      },
      {
        date: "2019-08-04",
        open: 132.94,
        high: 136.24,
        low: 132.63,
        close: 135.03,
      },
      {
        date: "2019-08-05",
        open: 136.76,
        high: 137.86,
        low: 132.0,
        close: 134.01,
      },
      {
        date: "2019-08-06",
        open: 131.11,
        high: 133.0,
        low: 125.09,
        close: 126.39,
      },
      {
        date: "2019-08-07",
        open: 130.11,
        high: 133.0,
        low: 125.09,
        close: 127.39,
      },
      {
        date: "2019-08-08",
        open: 125.11,
        high: 126.0,
        low: 121.09,
        close: 122.39,
      },
      {
        date: "2019-08-09",
        open: 131.11,
        high: 133.0,
        low: 122.09,
        close: 124.39,
      },
    ];

    var exporting = am5plugins_exporting.Exporting.new(root, {
      menu: am5plugins_exporting.ExportingMenu.new(root, {
        align: "left",
        // valign: "bottom",
      }),
      dataSource: data,
      filePrefix: "Group Analytics - Box Plot",
    });

    addMediana();

    function addMediana() {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dataItem = data[i];
        dataItem.mediana =
          Number(dataItem.low) +
          (Number(dataItem.high) - Number(dataItem.low)) / 2;
      }
    }

    series.data.processor = am5.DataProcessor.new(root, {
      dateFields: ["date"],
      dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
    });

    series.data.setAll(data);
    medianaSeries.data.setAll(data);

    // Make stuff animate on load
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
    series.appear(1000, 100);
    medianaSeries.appear(1000, 100);
    chart.appear(1000, 100);
    //---------------------------------------------------CHART LOGIC------------------------------------//
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        overflow: "hidden",
        paddingBottom: "56.25%",
        position: "relative",
        height: "0",
      }}
    >
      <div
        id={props.name}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: "0",
          top: "3vh",
          height: "calc(100vh - 300px)",
          width: "100%",
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Please do note that I'm using "date" as a placeholder for testing currently. Looking forward to someone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the configuration of your `xAxis`. Obviously, a **category axis** is not the same thing as a **value axis** or **date axis**. So the configuration is a bit different.

If I understand well your issue, you started coding from the demo given in the documentation ([Box Plot Chart - amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/box-plot-chart/)) and you are trying to change axis type to get a category axis. I see that you implemented the first steps correctly (because you use `categoryXField` in settings), but you forgot to push data to the axis: `xAxis.data.setAll(data);`

Moreover, you need to remove the following block because categories are strings, not date objects nor timestamps:

```
series.data.processor = am5.DataProcessor.new(root, {
  dateFields: ["date"],
  dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd"
});
```

Here is the final result:

```js
am5.ready(function() {

  var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {}));
  
  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: 'date',
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {})
  }));

  var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));

  var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.CandlestickSeries.new(root, {
    name: "MDXI",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    categoryXField: "date",
    valueYField: "close",
    openValueYField: "open",
    lowValueYField: "low",
    highValueYField: "high",
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
      labelText: "open: {openValueY}\nlow: {lowValueY}\nhigh: {highValueY}\nclose: {valueY},\nmediana: {mediana}"
    })
  }));

  var medianaSeries = chart.series.push(am5xy.StepLineSeries.new(root, {
    stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    categoryXField: "date",
    valueYField: "mediana",
    noRisers: true
  }));

  var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
    xAxis: xAxis,
  }));
  cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);

  var data = [
    {
      date: "2019-08-01",
      open: 132.3,
      high: 136.96,
      low: 131.15,
      close: 136.49,
    },
    {
      date: "2019-08-02",
      open: 135.26,
      high: 135.95,
      low: 131.5,
      close: 131.85,
    },
    {
      date: "2019-08-03",
      open: 129.9,
      high: 133.27,
      low: 128.3,
      close: 132.25,
    },
    {
      date: "2019-08-04",
      open: 132.94,
      high: 136.24,
      low: 132.63,
      close: 135.03,
    },
    {
      date: "2019-08-05",
      open: 136.76,
      high: 137.86,
      low: 132.0,
      close: 134.01,
    },
    {
      date: "2019-08-06",
      open: 131.11,
      high: 133.0,
      low: 125.09,
      close: 126.39,
    },
    {
      date: "2019-08-07",
      open: 130.11,
      high: 133.0,
      low: 125.09,
      close: 127.39,
    },
    {
      date: "2019-08-08",
      open: 125.11,
      high: 126.0,
      low: 121.09,
      close: 122.39,
    },
    {
      date: "2019-08-09",
      open: 131.11,
      high: 133.0,
      low: 122.09,
      close: 124.39,
    },
  ];

  function addMediana() {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var dataItem = data[i];
      dataItem.mediana = Number(dataItem.low) + (Number(dataItem.high) - Number(dataItem.low)) / 2;
    }
  }
  
  addMediana();

  xAxis.data.setAll(data); // Do not forget this step!
  series.data.setAll(data);
  medianaSeries.data.setAll(data);
  
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```